# Why does the first Python Loop Work and Not the second?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Why does this top loop work and not the second, commented-out loop?

```
rows = int(input('How many rows? '))

while rows <= 0 or rows >= 26:
    print('Out of range - must be between 1 and 25')
    rows = int(input('How many rows? '))
else:
    for n in range(rows):
        print('9' * 9 + '8' * 8 + '7' * 7 + '6' * 6 + '5' * 5 + '4' * 4 + '3' * 3 + '2' * 2 + '1')
     

'''
while rows <= 25 and rows >= 1:
    for n in range(rows):
        print('9' * 9 + '8' * 8 + '7' * 7 + '6' * 6 + '5' * 5 + '4' * 4 + '3' * 3 + '2' * 2 + '1')
else:
    print('Out of range - must be between 1 and 25')
    rows = int(input('How many rows? '))

'''
```

I expect both of these to produce n rows of these repeated nums as long as the input 'rows' is between 1 and 25. Obviously, that is not the case...

Comment: Saying that the second loop "does not work" is not a helpful description.  Show us what the loop **actually does**, and explain how that is different from what you **wanted**.

Comment: Beside the inappropriate use of `else`, the second loop will loop forever since it can not have exit condition. Would you mind to tell us what you actually want?

Comment: Hey, thank you all for the responses. I apologize for the simple question as it is my first on stack overflow. The else block only executes under falsy conditions and only does so once...is this correct?

Comment: There's nothing terribly inappropriate about the `else` clause in the first loop. (It's not particularly *necessary*, as the loop doesn't have a `break` statement that could prevent the `else` from executing, but that doesn't make it inappropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

The logic you proposed is already true, e.g.

```py
for rows in range(-2, 9, 1):
    cond1 = (rows <= 0) or (rows >= 6) 
    cond2 = (rows <= 5) and (rows >= 1) 
    print(rows, cond1, cond2)
```

will produce

```
-2 True False
-1 True False
0 True False
1 False True
2 False True
3 False True
4 False True
5 False True
6 True False
7 True False
8 True False
```

as expectedw, where

- `Cond1` gives `False` for 1 ≤ `rows` ≤ 5
- `Cond2` gives `True` for 1 ≤ `rows` ≤ 5

The problems are the use of `while` and `else`.